# ¿Se puede fijar la zona Horaria de una aplicacion desarrollada con ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo un aplicación web que al instalarla sobre un servidor en estados unidos me pone el horario del servidor.
Existe una forma de cambiar la zona Global de toda la app? para que cada vez que use

> DateTime.now

me traiga la hora correcta?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quizás en vez de utilizar "DateTime" podrías utilizar "DateTimeOffset", que es básicamente la misma clase de "DateTime" solo que toma datos también de la zona horaria.
Algo así si es una propiedad:

```
public DateTimeOffset FechaHora {get; set;}
```

También podrías investigar un poco sobre globalización(globalization) en el startup class de tu aplicación en ASP.NET Core. Eso te serviria para adaptar toda la info de un país o lugar a tu programa (moneda, formato numérica, fecha, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Para [localizar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) una app puedes deberias hacerla en el momento que el se configura, ya se por request (o sea que tome la configuracion de cliente, si un usuario que esta en otra zona horaria al servidor, o si ya quieres puedes definir la cultura especifica de toda la app tambien.

Te puede ayudar este enlace

- [Globalización y localización en ASP.NET Core > Implementar una estrategia para seleccionar el idioma o la referencia cultural de cada solicitud](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request)

Como veras se basa en proveedores o sea el responsable (la clase/objeto) de buscar alguna variable en QueryString, Cookies, y Accept Language - encabezado http), pero puedes hacer uno propio el ejemplo  es un proveedor por Url (midominio.com/es /en). Pero bueno es como introduccion simplemente a este tema de [localización](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)

Pero o es por request o tambien claro puedes configurarlo en app y ya dejarlo "estático", que seria como definir un proveedor estático, y para eso esta esta parte que te puede ayudar

- [Globalización y localización en ASP.NET Core > Usar un proveedor personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-custom-provider)

Mira el ejemplo, pero algo mas sencillo seria de setear la [DefaultRequestCulture](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.requestlocalizationoptions.defaultrequestculture)

```
private const string ESES_CULTURE = "es-ES";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
         options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: ESES_CULTURE,      uiCulture: ESES_CULTURE);

    });
```

}

En el ejemplo anterior era para Español España "es-es", pero te dejo aqui todos los codigos

- [Table of Language Culture Names, Codes, and ISO Values Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/commerce-server/ee825488(v=cs.20))

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.